# Reddits voting algorithm, javascript version

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math

i tried to write this function: http://uggedal.com/reddit.cf.algorithm.png in javascript:

```
function getRating(t,u,d){

        var x = u-d;

        if(x > 0)
            y = 1
        else if(x == 0)
            y = 0
        else if(x < 0)
            y = -1

        var z = Math.max(1,Math.abs(x));

        return Math.log(z)/Math.log(10) + y*t/45000;

    }
```

t = time in seconds between the first post and this post passed to the function
u = upvotes
d = downvotes

```
console.log(getRating(50000, 25, 25)); //0
```

But it always returns zero. Did i miss something? Thanks

edit: updated

Comment: When calculating z, you should be using the absolute value of x

Comment: Also, when U=D, the function will always return zero, as U=D => x=0 => y=0, and x=0 => z=1 => log(z) = 0

Comment: @animuson Math.log() is natural log, not base 10 log.

Comment: @animuson i googled and found out that `to find log10(n), use Math.log(n) / Math.log(10)`

Comment: Anyone with some javascript knowledge care to adjust the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example input, the result is 0, so that's correct. Does it return 0 also for other inputs?

One thing, according to the link, you should set

```
z = Math.max(1,Math.abs(x))
```

Comment: Ok, ive edited the question. Is it eqvivalent to the png now? It does not return zero when u <> d, so i guess it might be working now

Comment: @Johan You'd better declare `var y`, but the algorithm is equivalent. The result is always 0 when `u == d`, nonzero otherwise (except for one `t` value for each difference `u-d`).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. A final question: Why is a post where u != d more popular the older it becomes. Shouldnt it be the opposite here?

Comment: @Johan I have no idea why reddit rates as it does. Perhaps the thinking was that if a post has `u > d` after a long while it stood the test of time, if it weren't good, it would have attracted enough downvotes to compensate (analogously for `u < d`).

Comment: @Johan Ah, the `t` is not the time since posting, but the difference between posting time and some (arbitrary) point in the past, so later posts get a higher baseline (if `u > d`, lower if `u < d`), so it's 'hotter' if good. Assuming you pass a correctly calculated `t`, yes, your function works exactly as it should (one more point, in setting `y`, replace `else if (x < 0)` with plain `else`, it's cleaner).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5789/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-johan)

Answer (score 0):

Well in that case, z will be 1, and log(1) is 0.  Also, "y" will be 0 because u == d.

As is mentioned in the comments on the question, and as is clear from the linked .png file, you need to set "z" from the max of the absolute value of "x" and 1.  When "u" and "d" are the same however it'll always be zero anyway.